# apps doesn't work after update opencv manager

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I'm developing android apps based on opencv. I'm using Eclipse Juno, the android SDK, the android NDK r8, and opencv4android 2.4.3.

The problem is after update OpenCv Manager to 2.8 version my apps doesn't work, include the samples and tutorials from opencv4android, the phone only shows a black screen and then the app crash (appears the windows "The xxxxxxx doens't work, would you like close it?")

The LogCat of Eclipse shows the message:

---

```
OpenCVManager/Helper    Service connection created    
OpenCVManager/Helper    Trying to get library path    
OpenCVManager/Helper    Triying to get library list    
OpenCVManager/Helper    Library list ""    
OpenCVManager/Helper    Fist attemp to load libs    
OpenCVManager/Helper    Triying to init OpenCV libs    
OpenCVManager/Helper    Triying to load library     /data/data/org.opencv.en/lib/libopencv.java.so    
libc                    Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000154 (code=0)
```

---

after it the apps crash

I updated to opencv4android 2.4.6, updated the SDK, updated the ADT, and updated to Eclipse Kepler, but nothing work.....That is strange because before update OpenCV Manager to 2.8 all my apps worked correctly......

I use the async method with the line

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
```

Any solution?

PD: I use a Xperia ST21i

PD2: I don't use the emulator because it causes lag on my computer and I can't work

PD3: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have the same problem, I've just updated OpenCV manager and my application stoped working (Freezes) when tyring to initialize the opencv library.

the temproray solution is to fall back to older version, I got OpenCV manager 2.0 from the following website

http://android.brothersoft.com/opencv_manager-212868-download.html

try to download it and hope that solves your problem.

Comment: thanks for the tip, now my apps work correctly.......Really I want to know wich is the reason of this bug :S

Comment: I don't know what cause the problem, but I've tried the new version on different devices and for some of them it works for me, but for other devices it doesn't !!!